# BitmapDrawable does not respect scaleType on view

Tags: java, android

I want to display an image synchronously on a view, and I am using Universal Image Loader:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

On async call the library displays the image properly. Though, doing something like this:

```
myImageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("path/to/image")));
```

The image gets displayed, ignoring my scaleType on layout, which is centerCrop. I want to do this without having to process the image which would increase the load time. I have been searching Google for 4 hours now without luck. I landed on some threads in here but they are not helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setImageDrawable()` instead of `setBackground()`. Using the image as a background will always ignore the scale type.

```
myImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("path/to/image")));
```

Comment: You are right, Ben P. What is ironic is after I gave up searching Google I went and checked the source code for the library on displayImage and I have found it an hour ago. Thanks, though.